# Repeating view within a view in ASP MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If I have an elaborate repeating layout which I would like to only define once, say some fancy grid of boxes, but the content of those boxes would vary both in view and model from grid to grid (but not within a grid), e.g. one page has a fancygrid of product summaries and another page has a fancygrid of category introductions. What's the most sensible pattern for implementing that MVC3?

Answer (score 2):

You could use display templates. For example define a property on your view model that is of type `Enumerable<SomeViewModel>`:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SomeViewModel> Models { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view use the DisplayFor helper:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Models)
```

then define a custom display template that will automatically be rendered for each element of the Models collection (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SomeViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model SomeViewModel
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
    ...
</div>
```

Templated helpers work by convention. By default it will first look in the `~/Views/CurrentController/DisplayTemplates` folder and then in the `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` folder for a template which is named the same way as the type of the collection property (`SomeViewModel.cshtml`).

Comment: Sorry, if I do @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Models), then where does the loop which defines my grid layout fit in?

Comment: Nowhere. It's the framework that automatically does it for you and renders the display template for each item. You don't need to write any loops. ASP.NET MVC automatically recognizes that Models implements `IEnumerable<T>` so it will loop for you. It works by convention. Everything is convention over configuration.

Comment: But where does the html for the grid live?

Comment: It depends. You could have some part outside the template and other part in the template. It will all depend on how you are building your grids and what components you are using.

Comment: by default display and editor templates live in the EditorTemplates or DisplayTemplates folder in the views folder and the template name should match your model name unless you wish to set them manually see http://www.briankeating.net/post/2011/11/08/ASP-MVC-Display-Templates.aspx for some examples

Comment: My point of confusion about this answer is that in suggesting I do a Html.DisplayFor the entire collection, it leaves nowhere for my containing framework to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the repeating section into a partial view. Then that partial view can be reused anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Action GenreMenu in Store Controller:

```
  [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GenreMenu()
    {
        var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList();

        return PartialView(genres);
    }
```

in the View this will repeat the partial view three times:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
 Html.RenderAction("GenreMenu", "Store");
}
```